# Nested datatable while mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model-view-controller, mapping, reactjs.net

Basically I have two tables `products` and `categories`.
I managed to map out `products` with:

```
var ProductsList = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var EachProduct = this.props.data.map(function (item) {
        return (
                <SingleProduct key={item.Id } data={item}/>
        );
    });
    return (
        <ul>
            {EachProduct}
        </ul>
        );
}
```

});

...and there is yet that second table `categories`. I tried googling but I did not really knew how to google it. 
Normally I could just send two models to view from controller and could just do foreach in foreach and the second one would just look into `categories` for `fk_product_id` or something like that, so that `<SingleProduct/>` class could show all categories that are connected with mapped product ..but this is just a different story.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
render: function () {
var EachProduct = this.props.data.map(function (item) {
    var category = this.props.categories.find((categoryItem)=>{
         return (item.categoryId === categoryItem.id)
    })
    return (
            <SingleProduct key={item.Id } data={item} category={category}/>
    );
});
return (
    <ul>
        {EachProduct}
    </ul>
    );
```

}

Comment: but how will the single product know which categories to take out? Is there something like maping where id == x?

Comment: Hey.. I've assumed the mapping to be item.categoryId === categoryItem.id where item is the product. I'm assuming the relationship between product and category is one to one or many to one

Comment: The category mapped to each product will be returned by the find function

Comment: Oh right, I've skipped the find part for some reason. Forgive me. It is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. :)

Comment: :) glad to help

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. I've noticed that it currently returns only 1 category for each product. How would you make it to return a more if for example 1 product belongs to two categories, not just 1

Comment: instead of find, use filter. :) that would return an array of all the categories mapping to the product. Then you'd need to return the SingleProduct component for each category in the category array.